# Laravel - BelongsToMany retrive only current related record

Tags: laravel

I have two models, `Ricetta` and `Ingrediente` and this relationships:

Ingrediente.php

```
public function ricetta()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Ricetta', 'ricetta_has_ingrediente', 'ingrediente_id', 'ricetta_id')->withPivot('qta', 'unita_misura_id');
    }
```

Ricetta.php

```
public function ingrediente()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Models\Ingrediente', 'ricetta_has_ingrediente', 'ricetta_id', 'ingrediente_id')->withPivot('qta', 'unita_misura_id');
    }
```

So, with this query I can retrive all `Ingrediente` in `Ricetta`:

```
$result = $model->newQuery()
    ->select('ingrediente.*')
    ->with('ricetta')
    ->whereHas('ricetta', function($query){
        $query->where('ricetta_has_ingrediente.ricetta_id', 1);
      })->get();
```

It works, but in `$result->ricetta`  I have all the `Ricetta` with the `Ingredinte`, not only the current `Ricetta` (with id = 1).

How I can modify the query to retrive only the current Ricetta?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass constraints to each relationship when you load them:

```
$result = $model->newQuery()
    ->select('ingrediente.*')
    ->with([
        'ricetta' => static function($query) {
            $query->where('ricetta.id', 1);
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```